# Capture groups with Regular Expression (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Kind of a noob here, apologies if I misstep.

I'm learning regular expressions and am on this lesson:
https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups.

In the python interpreter, I try to use the parentheses to only capture what precedes the .pdf part of the search string but my result captures it despite using the parens. What am I doing wrong?

```
import re
string_one = 'file_record_transcript.pdf'
string_two = 'file_07241999.pdf'
string_three = 'testfile_fake.pdf.tmp'

pattern = '^(file.+)\.pdf$'
a = re.search(pattern, string_one)
b = re.search(pattern, string_two)
c = re.search(pattern, string_three)

print(a.group() if a is not None else 'Not found')
print(b.group() if b is not None else 'Not found')
print(c.group() if c is not None else 'Not found')
```

Returns

```
file_record_transcript.pdf
file_07241999.pdf
Not found
```

But should return

```
file_record_transcript
file_07241999
Not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need the *first* captured group:

```
a.group(1)
b.group(1)
...
```

without any captured group specification as argument to [`group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), it will show the full match, like what you're getting now.

Here's an example:

```
In [8]: string_one = 'file_record_transcript.pdf'

In [9]: re.search(r'^(file.*)\.pdf$', string_one).group()
Out[9]: 'file_record_transcript.pdf'

In [10]: re.search(r'^(file.*)\.pdf$', string_one).group(1)
Out[10]: 'file_record_transcript'
```

Comment: Oh wow, the first capture group is 1 and not 0? Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `match[index]`

```js
a[0] => Full match (file_record_transcript.pdf)
a[1] => First group (file_record_transcript)
a[2] => Second group (if any)
```