# Removing parts of text being written to a CSV after scraping

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm fooling around with a script that parses [this](https://in.rsdelivers.com) website for the component stock number, price, HSN code etc. I'm building the URL from a list of stock numbers (given below) and then using `BeautifulSoup` to scrape parts of the site. I'm able to see the output that I need (shown below) and write it to a CSV file.

[image]

How do I get rid of the text `RS Stock No.`, `HSN Code` and `Brand` and only write the values to the CSV? The contents of `rs_tmp.csv` are as follows:

```
553431
553437
553453
6738708
```

The code is as follows,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('csv/rs_tmp.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    rs_cmp_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    with open('urls_folder/rs_tmp.txt', 'r') as url_file:
        for line in url_file:
            url = "https://in.rsdelivers.com/productlist/search?query=" + line.lstrip()
            cmp_data = []

            source = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

            for snippet in soup.find_all('div', class_='row-inline pill-component-module_pill-component__1WRtv pill-component-module_grey__38ctb'):
                stock_num_part_num = snippet.text
                cmp_data.append(stock_num_part_num)

            for snippet in soup.find_all('div', class_='add-to-basket-cta-component_price-block__1agRR'):
                price = snippet.div.p.text
                cmp_data.append(price)

            rs_cmp_writer.writerow(cmp_data)

print()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use Regular expressions with capture groups. Capture groups allow you to drop part of the matched expression, such as `HSN Code`. Here's a stackoverflow question on regex with some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719537/capture-groups-with-regular-expression-python/48719548

Comment: how about simple `text = text.replace("RS Stock No. ", "").replace("HSN Code ", "").replace("Brand ", "")`. OR split it to `cmp_data[0] = cmp_data[0].replace("RS Stock No. ", "")` `cmp_data[1] = cmp_data[1].replace("Brand ", "")`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simple replace values before saving

```
if len(cmp_data) > 2:
    cmp_data[0] = cmp_data[0].replace("RS Stock No. ", "") 
    cmp_data[1] = cmp_data[1].replace("Brand ", "")
    cmp_data[2] = cmp_data[2].replace("HSN Code ", "")

rs_cmp_writer.writerow(cmp_data)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you can do it in one line but this will be less readable.

```
stock_num_part_num = snippet.text.replace("RS Stock No. ", "").replace("HSN Code ", "").replace("Brand ", "")
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but I had to replace the strings in the `for` loops.

Comment: I put `writerow` in example to show where you have to use it in your `for`-loop.