# Replace An Exact Grouped Part in RegEx Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re, regexp-replace, python-regex

I have a template that I need to replace a part of that using Regex in Python. Here is my template: (Note that there is at least a new line between two comments)

```html
hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
some text
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here
```

I want to replace everything between `<!--POSTS:START-->` and `<!--POSTS:END-->` in Python. So I made `<!--POSTS:START-->\n([^;]*)\n<!--POSTS:END-->` pattern but it includes `<!--POSTS:START-->` and `<!--POSTS:END-->` too.

Here is what I want:

```py
re.sub('...', 'foo', message)

# expected result:
hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
foo
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create a **capturing group** within your pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719537/capture-groups-with-regular-expression-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group for the start and end markers and reference those as \1, \2, etc in the target replacement string.

If the text has multiple occurrences of `<!--POSTS:START-->...<!--POSTS:END-->` then the regexp with `.*?` will replace each of those groups. If the '?' is removed the regexp then it will remove all text from the start of the first group to the end of the last group.

Try this:

```python
import re

s = '''
hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
some text
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here
'''

# for multi-line matching need extra flags in the regexp
s = re.sub(r'(<!--POSTS:START-->\n).*?(\n<!--POSTS:END-->)', r'\1foo\2', s, flags=re.DOTALL)

# this inlines the DOTALL flag in the regexp for same result
# s = re.sub(r'(?s)(<!--POSTS:START-->\n).*?(\n<!--POSTS:END-->)', r'\1foo\2', s)

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
foo
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What if I have nothing but a `\n` between two comment lines?

Comment: Also, I tried your pattern with multiple lines between the two comment lines but didn't work!

Comment: Add flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL parameter to the re.sub() call.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `re.DOTALL` seems to be all you need: `re.MULTILINE` only alters the behavior of `^` and `$`, so it should have no effect here.

Comment: @fsimonjetz - yes since . is in regexp and want to include '\n' then only 
 re.DOTALL flag is needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
import re

new_content = re.sub(
    r'(<!--POSTS:START-->\n).*?(?=\n<!--POSTS:END-->)', r"\1foo",
    content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The flags DOTALL: Make the '.' special character matches any character at all, including a newline.

I'm using two things to do what you want

- Group lookahead `"?="`: Asserts that the given subpattern can be matched here, without consuming characters
- Non greedy match pattern (*?). This will match in a non greedy mode. This way we get all patterns separatly

As we are using lookahead, `\n<!--POSTS:END-->` will not be consumed so I only need to keep the first group and rewrite the content between the matches. That is why I'm using `\1foo` and not `\1foo\2`

If you need to modify only the first match you can use `count=1`

```
re.sub(..., count=1)
```

You can have anything between those two lines and it will work as expected

Comment: Thank you. What if I have a few more of those two-line comments? It actually removed the first matched and applies changes to the second one,

Comment: Hi, I figure it out. I will edit my post. Please mark as answer if it fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re

pattern = r"(<!--POSTS:START-->\n).*(\n<!--POSTS:END-->)"
string = """hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
some text
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here"""
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\g<1>foo\g<2>", string)
print(result)
```

result:

```
hello
how's everything

<!--POSTS:START-->
foo
<!--POSTS:END-->

Some code here
```